# To pool or combine multiple correlations: Pearson and ICC

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis, pearson-r, intraclass-correlation

For part of a study we are running, we are investigating the correlation between a post-practice score, and the subsequent day's pre-practice score. We are looking at the potential association between the two. This is because if someone scores low (or high) on a test pre-practice, a decision will be made on whether they will practice, or need to do a lower intensity practice as they may not have recovered enough. So we are looking at whether knowledge of a post practice assessment the day before, will provide some information on how well they will likely recover. If it does, we can then put into place over the time between practices an intervention to improve recovery.

So we have a set of data after one practice, and the same test performed pre-practice the next day. We have this for multiple pairs of days (>20) throughout the season. The scores are ratio type data.

So we have 28 players, but very rarely will we have 28 people training each practice (injuries, missed practices etc etc). We have over 20 pairs of practices.

I am proposing utilising three correlation models to better understand the data:
1 - ICC with agreement to assess fit of a y=x model: this would effectively be high only if no change in the scores occur between the two practices
2 - ICC with consistency to assess fit of a y=x+b model: this would tell us if there is a consistent change across the whole group i.e. just a mean difference
3 - Pearson to assess for of a y=mx+b model: this would tell us if people change at different rates based on their first score

We are running the three models for each post-pre practice pair. So have a number of correlations across the season.

My question is, what is the most appropriate way to combine the correlations across the season. We are not showing a trend of the season, and so are wanting to pool the correlations from over the season (kind of like meta-analysing correlations from multiple studies) to get an overall estimate of the fit of the models.

I don't feel comfortable just combining all the data and then running a single correlation due to the same set of participants occurring multiple times. For the Pearson correlation, I am thinking about taking the approach suggested by Hodges and others (transforming the r to z statistic and weighting based on the sample size etc
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6915/6e28b99c6fa2693c63ca5f104980dcbe15e3.pdf

However, for the ICC, how best to do this. Is there a way of pooling multiple ICCs, whilst also taking the 95% CI from these, instead of post calculating this using an alternative approach?

Or is there a more appropriate way of looking at this.

Thank you in advance